# Unable to use CreateView.as_view in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm new to Django and trying to use CBV to generate a form for my 'Project' model. When I use the **CreateView.as_view(...)** in **urls.py** it gives the following error.

```
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreateView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
```

I'm listing the full code related to this view.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^create-project/$', CreateView.as_view(model=Project,
                                             template_name='en/public/create_project.html',
                                             success_url='index'),
                                             name='create_project')
```

**create_project.py**

```
class Form_project_create(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

I cannot figure our what's wrong in this code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told the CreateView to use that form.

```
url(r'^create-project/$', CreateView.as_view(form=Form_project_create, ...
```

Note also, the form itself needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm`, not `forms.Form`.

Answer (score 0):

Form_project_create should be inheriting forms.ModelForm, not forms.Form

```
class Form_project_create(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```